# Problem with c++ leetcode compiler while compile a code { local compiler and online compiler gives different result for the same code }

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, testcase

This is the problem i am trying to solve, along with the solution testing the test case in which i am having trouble in.

[Leetcode problem: 128. Longest Consecutive Sequence](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-consecutive-sequence/description/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

class Solution {
public:
    int longestConsecutive(std::vector<int>& nums)
    {
        std::unordered_map<int, int> seq;
        for (auto i : nums)
        {
            ++seq[i];
        }
        int max{ 0 };
        for (auto i : seq)
        {
            int ans{ 0 };
            int x{ i.first };
            if (seq[x] > 0)
            {
                ans = 1;
                int p{ x };
                int q{ x };
                while (seq[p - 1] > 0)
                {
                    --p;
                    ++ans;
                }
                while (seq[q + 1] > 0)
                {
                    ++q;
                    ++ans;
                }
            }
            if (max < ans)
                max = ans;
        }
        return max;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solution s;
    std::vector<int> nums{ 4,0,-4,-2,2,5,2,0,-8,-8,-8,-8,-1,7,4,5,5,-4,6,6,-3 };
    std::cout << s.longestConsecutive(nums);
    return 0;
}
```

When i tested this test case in my offline compiler(microsoft c++ compiler in visualt studio), it is showing the test case ans as 5(which is absolutely correct).

[image: microsoft visual studio debug console screenshot]

However, upon submitting the same solution in leetcode it is showing the test case ans as 4(which is wrong). I tried testing this case in online gdb compiler also and there also this test case ans is showing as 4.

[image: Leetcode failed test case screenshot]

My solution has passed 55/72 cases so i am sure there is not any issue with my algorithm or my answer output format. I believe it to be an issue with leetcode or online

Comment: what is your specific question? How to find the bug? -> [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Umm, but if you can reproduce your problem with the other compiler (e.g. online godbolt), then just debug it there?

Comment: The issue is your code, not the compiler. Let's not be so arrogant. Differing results means you've (very likely) invoked Undefined Behavior. I wouldn't consider this the best way to solve this problem either.

Comment: probably not the problem, but why do you use `seq[x]` in the loop rather than `i.second` ?

Comment: You are modifying the map while looping over it. This invalidates the iterators.

Comment: These test are designed (1) to break (time/memory exceeded) if you try the obvious algorithm and (2) test your program with edge-test-cases ie completely within the spec but not usual data eg the empty test case, maximum and minimum integers ...  The example test-cases are usually easy to pass using the obvious approach and the hidden test-cases are usually not.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @OP *so i am sure there is not any issue with my algorithm* -- A program that you write is *not* an algorithm.  An algorithm is a set of steps that will *always* give the correct answer.  A program that you write that implements the algorithm can have bugs.  That's the difference -- your program has bugs.

Comment: I could not answer, because again the question has been closed too quick. Not good. Solution is here: https://godbolt.org/z/WaM6ebxq5   Why is ist necessary to close a question after 30min?

Comment: Thinking that the fault is anywhere but with yourself is not an efficient way to find bugs.

Comment: I am new to data structures and thought i have understood maps quite well. It wasn't though. Thanks everyone for providing useful input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider your code (shortened for brevity)

```
    for (auto i : seq)
    {
        int x{ i.first }; 
        if (seq[x] > 0) // okay, will be in the sequence
        {
            int p{ x };
            int q{ x };
            while (seq[p - 1] > 0) // p-1 might not be in the map, so insert
            {}
            while (seq[q + 1] > 0) // q+1 might not be in the map, so insert
            {}
        }
    }
```

Both these while loops can cause insertions, which *can* invalidate the iterators used by `for (auto i : seq)`. Thus, you have Undefined Behaviour, and getting anywhere near the correct result is more by accident.

Comment: sadly address sanitizer is unable to catch that: https://godbolt.org/z/hb8deeb8b

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new to maps and hence didn't knew that i was unknowingly inserting new keys in the map. I have now successfully found an alternate way to do this by using condition (seq.find(p - 1) != seq.end().

Answer (score 1):

With your issue pointed out (invaliding iterators due to inserts), here's a working solution. It beats 80.33% on runtime and 60.17% on memory:

```cpp
class Solution {
 public:
  int longestConsecutive(vector<int>& nums) {
    std::unordered_set<int> uniqueVals;

    // Fill set
    for (auto& i : nums) {
      uniqueVals.insert(i);
    }

    int maxSequence = 0;
    // Iterate the set instead of the vector to avoid re-checking
    // repeated values in the vector.
    for (auto& i : uniqueVals) {
      // Is number the start of a sequence?
      if (uniqueVals.find(i - 1) != uniqueVals.end()) {
        continue;  // It was not, we move on immediately
      }

      // Getting here means our value is the start of a sequence
      int sequenceLength = 1;
      for (int val = i + 1; uniqueVals.find(val) != uniqueVals.end();
           ++val, ++sequenceLength) {
      }
      if (sequenceLength > maxSequence) {
        maxSequence = sequenceLength;
      }
    }

    return maxSequence;
  }
};
```

This answer was accepted by leetcode, so it passes all tests.

The big idea is identifying the start of a sequence. I use `std::unordered_set` because I don't care how many times a value has occurred, and I get O(1) insertion. I only care if a value is in the set or not.

More importantly, I don't modify the set  with insertions as I'm iterating it (read-only), which keeps my loop well-defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't knew about the sets until now.

Comment: I wold argue that you are learning in reverse order. You should have a solid foundation *before* you tackle leetcode.

Comment: I myself am feeling the same. It is taking a lot of time just for solving one question.